Identifying a 3 pin SOT SMD chip marked MU
Working to repair a Casio CDP-220R piano which has water/coffee damage to a portion of the keyboard. Found a 3 pin SOT smd with what looks to be marked MU X (double dot below the x)
Edit 1: dimension of chip are approx 2.1mm * 1.6mm non inclusive of pins
Edit 2: clarify 3-pin SOT of unknown package, not SOT-3 package.


SOT-3 is not a package I'm familiar with. This looks like either a SOT-23, SOT-323, or SOT-523.

@Daedaleus thanks

@Hearth clarified title/post to note it's a 3 pin SOT not a SOT-3 package.

Coffee (or water) alone won't damage the parts, clean the board and look for PCB trace damage via corrosion first.

It is a M1MA142WK dual diode from Onsemi.
Picture from lcsc:

